# MySQL Workbench (GUI) is not installing

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

It has installed following in C:\Program Files\MySQL  :
1. Connector.C++ 1.1,
2. Connector.J 5.1,
3. Connector.NET 6.9,
4. Connector.ODBC 5.3
5. MySQL Connector Python 2.1 for Python 3.4,
6. MySQL Connector.C 6.1,
7. MySQL Documentation 5.7,
8. MySQL For Excel 1.3,
9. MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2,
10.MySQL Installer for Windows,
11.MySQL Notifier 1.1,
12.MySQL Server 5.7,
13.MySQL Utilities 1.6,
14.Samples and Examples 5.7

and in C:\ProgramData\MySQL
MySQL Installer for Windows,MySQL Server 5.7,MySQL Server 5.7my_2017-04-15T05-15-55

I am able to see all other commands in start menu other than Workbench.

Kindly guide me how to install Workbench GUI.

Previously it was installed but when I uninstalled and reinstalled I am not able to find.
My system is Windows 10 32 bit

Comment: There is no 32bit version of MySQL Workbench anymore.

Comment: @Mike, My problem was that I was using zip version of downloader which was not installing GUI rest was done properly. I could not find any source on Internet which could guide me. Now I used  mysql-installer-web-community file. My problem was solved just now. But as you mentioned It is written on Mysql site 'Note: MySQL Installer is 32 bit, but will install both 32 bit and 64 bit binaries.'

Comment: I have uninstalled MySQL fully from Program File, Program Data, AppData,

Comment: Don't confuse the installer with the MySQL Workbench. The installer is a 32bit app and installs other apps, both 32bit and 64bit, where it matters. For some tools it does not (e.g. .NET connectors) and others have no 32bit version anymore, like WB.

Comment: @Mike, Pl. let me know why the problem happened and why it is solved, so in future it may helpful for others too. If possible in details. I am a new learner.

Comment: I thought it would be clear now, but let me make this a normal answer.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL installer for Windows is a 32bit app that can install other packages from MySQL, takes care for updates and checks the availability of new product versions. It can install products on 32bit and 64bit Windows platforms. MySQL Workbench however only comes as a 64bit program, which obviously cannot be installed on a 32bit OS. Hence it doesn't even appear in the installer when run on such a machine. 32bit OSes are becomming rather uncommon these days...